# How can I use PowerShell to make remote registry changes?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, remote-registry

I have tested the following PowerShell registry settings and it sets them correctly.
Could someone show me the way to do this for a remote computer?

```
New-Item -itemType String HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\Server0ps -Value "MY.DOMAIN.COM"
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers -Name 1 -Value "whatever" 
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities -Name "Hello" -Value 4
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities -Name "There" -Value 8
```

Comment: Take a look here (great Shay Levi work!) : http://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yeah but sadly I don't want to use a third party modules for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this as example:

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername ) 
        $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",$true) 
        $regKey.SetValue("New_Valuename_String","New_Valuedata",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
```

To create a new key you need use powershell remoting with `invoke-command` for `new-item` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [the PSRemoteRegistry PowerShell Module](http://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/), and its version for PowerShell 3.0 (with x86.x64 support, http://psrr.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete a key

```
$exchangeServers = @("xxxxx");
$hive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine;
$key = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa";

foreach ($exchangeServer in $exchangeServers)
{
    $regBaseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $exchangeServer.ToString());
    $regKeys = $regBaseKey.OpenSubKey($key,$true);
    $beforeVal = $regKeys.GetValue("DisableLoopbackCheck");
    Write-Host $exchangeServer " - " $beforeVal;
    $regKeys.DeleteValue("DisableLoopbackCheck"); # a try catch can be placed here if there is a concern the key won't exist
    $keyNames = $regKeys.GetSubKeyNames();
    $afterVal = $regKeys.GetValue("DisableLoopbackCheck");
    if ($afterVal -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host $exchangeServer " - deleted" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen;
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $exchangeServer " - " $afterVal -ForegroundColor Red;
    }
    Write-Host " ";
}
```