# Editing registry keys remotely with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to edit a registry key remotely with a Powershell script? If it is, how?

I have a list of 7 servers in which I have to disable windows update settings. I've coded the following script but only can be used localy:

```
$regkey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\microsoft\......\auto update"
set-itemproperty -path $regkey -name AUOptions -value 1
set-itemproperty -path $regkey -name ElevateNonAdmins -value 0
set-itemproperty -path $regkey -name IncludeRecommendedUpdates -value 0
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18896763/520612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell's support for remote registry is done via .Net. There are *lots* of Google answers available. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069130/get-remote-registry-value) from right this site:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer1)
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Veritas\\NetBackup\\CurrentVersion")
```

As for how to set the values is left as an exercise to the reader.