# How to send Atl sequence of keys tu regedit

Tags: powershell, vbscript, key, sendkeys

I need to open regedit on remote computer, I script it in powershell but the Alt keys %(FC) was not sended to regedit

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
$Process = start-process regedit -PassThru
Start-Sleep -m 500

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($Process.id)
Start-Sleep -m 500

#[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%(FC)")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$serverName")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("~~")
```

if i try it on notpad, it's works but not on regedit !

Comment: PowerShell can interact with the registry _really_ easy. Why do you need sendkeys?

Comment: I need to open regedit on remote computer, have you an other methode ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896248/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-make-remote-registry-changes

Comment: I need browse remote registry not read/write a specific item

Answer (score 1):

for send keys with powershell you should use `wscript.shell`
like this:

```
$server="dc"
  $user="user"
   $password="password"
$a = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
[void] $a.run("regedit")
Start-Sleep 3
$a.SendKeys("%f")
Start-Sleep 2
$a.SendKeys("c")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.SendKeys("$server")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.SendKeys("$user")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.sendkeys("{TAB}")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.SendKeys("$password")
Start-Sleep 1
$a.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep 1
Get-Process -Name regedit | Stop-Process
```

Comment: this code not wirk on my Win8, regedit open properly but no sendkeys()

Comment: hello dear @Alban i test scrip in win2k12 r2 and i run powershell as administrator because when you want run regedit you may privilege because check with uac you should run as administrator or off uac